# Authenticate flutter app with keycloak and openid_client

Tags: flutter, client, openid, keycloak

I'm trying to authenticate my flutter app to keycloak through [openid_client](https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client)

following the repo example, I've wrote an authentication function like this

```
authenticate() async {

  // parameters here just for the sake of the question
  var uri = Uri.parse('https://keycloak-url/auth/realms/myrealm');
  var clientId = 'my_client_id';
  var scopes = List<String>.of(['openid', 'profile']);
  var port = 4200;
  var redirectUri = Uri.parse('http://localhost:4200');

  var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
  var client = new Client(issuer, clientId);

  urlLauncher(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  var authenticator = new Authenticator(client,
      scopes: scopes,
      port: port,
      urlLancher: urlLauncher,
      redirectUri: redirectUri);

  var c = await authenticator.authorize();
  closeWebView();

  var token= await c.getTokenResponse();
  print(token);
  return token;
}
```

when I call the function, a webview popup appears and I can login through keycloak, but when the popup closes I get this error at the `c.getTokenResponse()`:

> Exception has occurred.
>   NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: length)

inspecting the Credential `c`, I can see that the TokenResponse has only "state", "session_state" and "code" fields

what am I missing?

Comment: For anyone interested to implement authorisation flow on the web. It appears this is a sample for android/ios. Currently the `Authenticator` that `openid_client` provides for the browser supports only the implicit flow as far as I can see from the source code. I'm trying to figure out if I can write my own Authenticator that can support authorisation flow on the web. I was hopping to find this as part of the library. No clear docs/reason are provided as to why implicit flow is  used on the web as long as it is currently deprecated and advised against.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been answered on github ([link](https://github.com/appsup-dart/openid_client/issues/11#issuecomment-603232319)), so I'll copy the solution here:

---

On mobile devices you should use the PKCE flow. This is automatically selected when you omit the redirect uri in the Authenticator constructor.

So, it should be:

```dart
var authenticator = new Authenticator(client,
      scopes: scopes,
      port: port,
      urlLancher: urlLauncher,);
```

Make sure you add the uri `http://localhost:4200/` (including the trailing slash) to `Valid Redirect URIs` in keycloak.

[image]

Make sure you add the uri http://localhost:4200/ (including the trailing slash) to Valid Redirect URIs in keycloak.

Comment: Do you have to open browser window for this?

Comment: openid_client plugin opens a webview when you call `await authenticator.authorize();`

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: You can use the resource owner password flow, but thats OAuth2 not OpenID and is not recommended due to security reasons. And you loose SSO and federation providers.